# mysql Different characters are recognized as the same,why

Tags: mysql

eg：あ ア These two characters are merged when grouping
encoding ：utf8mb4 
Two characters should have different encodings,Why is this happening?

```
>CREATE TABLE `test` (
>`keyword` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
>`show` int(11) NOT NULL
>) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
>insert into test (keyword,show) values('あ',5),('ア',10)；
>select keyword,sum(show) from test group by keyword;
>+---------------------------+----------------+
>| keyword                   | sum(show)    |
>+---------------------------+----------------+
>| あ                        |             15 |
```

Comment: how did you grouped ? if you compare them by BINARY value ... what you get?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I updated the question again.

Comment: if I compare them by BINARY value,they are different,Will not merge.

Comment: ok, and if you change to group by BINARY(keyword) ... ?

Comment: The reason is the collation

Comment: so you found solution?  you change to utf8mb4_unicode_ci ?

Comment: utf8mb4_unicode_ci  still merge，utf8mb4_bin and utf8mb4_general_ci will not merge